# Laravel - How to call a controller function via AJAX (jQuery)

Tags: ajax, laravel, function, controller, response

I have a number of working controller functions, however, for usability I want to switch some of them over to be called via AJAX.

Here is my jQuery code:

```
$.ajax({
        method: 'GET',
        url: $(this).data('url'),
        data: {},
        success: function( response ){
            console.log( response );
        },
        error: function( e ) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    });
```

And here is my controller function:

```
public function add( $user_id, $project_id )
{

    $project = Project::findOrFail( $project_id );

    if( empty( $project ) ) {

        return view( 'home' )->with('message', 'Sorry, user not found');

    }

    if ( $project->user_id != $user_id ) {

        $scrapbook = Scrapbook::firstOrNew(['user_id' => $user_id]);

        $scrapbook->save();

        $scrapbook->projects()->attach($project_id);

        return true;

    } else {

        return false;

    }
}
```

As it stands, the controller function actually does what it is supposed to (adds a project to a scrapbook). But what it returns is causing the AJAX request to class as an **error** so I am unable to handle this correctly. I assume I am supposed to return some kind of response object but I don't know what this is or what it needs to include.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may return a json response on success:

```
public function add( $user_id, $project_id )
{
    // Other code ...

    $isSuccess = false;

    if ($project->user_id != $user_id) {

        $scrapbook = Scrapbook::firstOrNew(['user_id' => $user_id]);

        if ($isSuccess = $scrapbook->save()) {
            // only attach it if successfully saved
            $scrapbook->projects()->attach($project_id);
        }

    }

    return response()->json([
        'success' => $isSuccess
    ]);
}
```

So in your `ajax` response you can check:

```
success: function( response ){
    console.log( response.success ); // true or false
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply return an array containing whether it is success or it is failed.

```
$output_data = ['response' => true, 'message' => 'request is successful.' ];
$output_data = ['response' => false, 'message' => 'error message for user.' ];
return $output_data;
```

This will return control in success block of ajax.
You can check there is the `response` is `true` or `false` and execute the code accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to return a [json response](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/responses#json-responses)  using  `json()` fucntion

```
return response()->json(true);
```

or if want to send additional data back

```
return response()->json([
   'message' => 'successfull',
   'items' =>$insertedItems
],200);
```

or on fail

```
return response()->json(['error'=>'error text'],$statusCode)
```

Answer (score 1):

In Routes:

```
Route::get('/url', 'controller_name@controller_function');
```

Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'url',
    data: {},
    success: function( response ){
        console.log( response );
    },
    error: function( e ) {
        console.log(e);
    }
});
```

In response , send json:

```
return response()->json(['message' => 'successfull'],200);
```

Comment: I would've send it, if I was fast enough haha.